# Bootstrap Slider Carousel with thumbnail navigation issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Original code
http://www.bootply.com/79859

When the gallery reaches 11 and above images clicking the 11th thumbnail shows the first image on the slider instead of the 11th. Can you help me with a fix for this?

Here is the code with more than 10 images.

http://www.bootply.com/x8UNRXg83S#

Comment: Always put your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 8 in your javascript code, you substring only the last character of your element id. 
When substringing 10 or any other number that has more than one digit, only the last digit will be used.

carousel-selector-10 -> 0

carousel-selector-11 -> 1

etc.

This is why it restarts after the id number is more than 2 digits long.

You could repalce that line with the following to make it work:

```
 var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```